# Is it possible to replace sub-queries, used as a scalar value, with CTE?

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression

I want to replace a long sub-query that return a scalar value or does not exist with just a short alias, because I place it 3 times to the UPDATE statement. Sub-query takes the last value in `UncoveredLoss`, if there is one, and the new `UncoveredLoss` value is calculated in the updated row depending on the last `UncoveredLoss` value.

It is a non-correlated query, but it is used in `SELECT` clause, not in the `FROM` clause. Maybe I should somehow modify the `UPDATE` statement in the trigger.

The working code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Result

UPDATE OF Win ON Log

BEGIN
    UPDATE Log
    SET Profit = CASE 
            WHEN NEW.Win = 0
                THEN - Stake
            WHEN NEW.Win = 1
                THEN Rate * Stake / 100
            WHEN NEW.Win = 2
                THEN 0
            END
    WHERE ID = OLD.ID;

    UPDATE Log
    SET SumProfit = (
            SELECT Sum(Profit)
            FROM (
                SELECT StrategyAccountID
                    ,Profit
                FROM Log
                WHERE DATE <= NEW.DATE
                )
            GROUP BY StrategyAccountID
            HAVING StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
            )
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;

    UPDATE Log
    SET UncoveredLoss = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (
                    SELECT UncoveredLoss
                    FROM Log
                    WHERE DATE < NEW.DATE
                        AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
                    ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                    )
                AND (
                    SELECT UncoveredLoss
                    FROM Log
                    WHERE DATE < NEW.DATE
                        AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
                    ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                    ) + NEW.Profit < 0
                THEN (
                        SELECT UncoveredLoss
                        FROM Log
                        WHERE DATE < NEW.DATE
                            AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
                        ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                        ) + NEW.Profit
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT UncoveredLoss
                    FROM Log
                    WHERE DATE < NEW.DATE
                        AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
                    ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                    )
                AND NEW.Profit < 0
                THEN NEW.Profit
            ELSE 0
            END
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```

The simple replacement of the sub-query using CTE not working:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Result

UPDATE OF Win ON Log

BEGIN
    UPDATE Log
    SET Profit = CASE 
            WHEN NEW.Win = 0
                THEN - Stake
            WHEN NEW.Win = 1
                THEN Rate * Stake / 100
            WHEN NEW.Win = 2
                THEN 0
            END
    WHERE ID = OLD.ID;

    UPDATE Log
    SET SumProfit = (
            SELECT Sum(Profit)
            FROM (
                SELECT StrategyAccountID
                    ,Profit
                FROM Log
                WHERE DATE <= NEW.DATE
                )
            GROUP BY StrategyAccountID
            HAVING StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
            )
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;

    WITH Loss
    AS (
        SELECT UncoveredLoss
        FROM Log
        WHERE DATE < NEW.DATE
            AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
        ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1
        )
    UPDATE Log
    SET UncoveredLoss = CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (Loss)
                AND (Loss) + NEW.Profit < 0
                THEN (Loss) + NEW.Profit
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (Loss)
                AND NEW.Profit < 0
                THEN NEW.Profit
            ELSE 0
            END
    WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```

> Error: near "UPDATE": syntax error

It works nicely when I don't replace the sub-query, but when I try to use CTE it fails. I work in sql.el mode in Emacs.

Comment: [WITH is supported in triggers](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html), but that's not how you use a CTE. It's like a view or table, you need something like `(SELECT Loss FROM Loss)` to refer to a scalar value returned by it.

Comment: Also pretty sure that can be rewritten to use a single update with a lot fewer subqueries. At first glance there's some strange looking stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that can be cleaned up a lot. Consider something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Result UPDATE OF Win ON Log BEGIN
  UPDATE Log
  SET SumProfit = (SELECT sum(Profit)
                   FROM Log
                   WHERE Date <= NEW.Date AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID)
    , UncoveredLoss = ifnull((SELECT min(UncoveredLoss + NEW.Profit, 0)
                              FROM Log
                              WHERE Date < NEW.Date AND StrategyAccountID = NEW.StrategyAccountID
                              ORDER BY Date DESC
                              LIMIT 1), 0)
  WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```

which I'm pretty sure calculates the same results as yours. (Actual sample table definition and data to work with would be nice)

Also note that in recent Sqlite3 releases (3.25 and later), your `SumProfit` column can easily be computed on demand instead of taking up space in the table:

```
SELECT *
     , sum(profit) OVER (PARTITION BY StrategyAccountID ORDER BY Date) AS SumProfit
FROM Log;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your completely correct answer! I have just corrected my question to add the full code of the trigger, to pretify the code and, what more important, to kill a bug. Now it requires even more sub-queries! But in your code all I needed to replace was: instead of `LIMIT 1), 0)`: `LIMIT 1), min(-NEW.Profit, 0))`. You may want to change that in your answer to reflect the corrected code in the question. And yes, you are right that SumProfit is not a necessary column, it can be added to a `VIEW` instead if I want to see the progress on every row.